# Design Pattern for Creating API URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I am building a class library that interacts with various 3rd party API's. I have used an facade pattern to provide simplified access to complicated and confusing calls, and a factory pattern to return the correct implementation. I am now trying to build one of the implementation but cant think of an elegant design.

The implementation i am building requires a URL to be constructed (which i am doing via URIBuilder). I then need to "execute" the url. I then deserialize the Xml result into a class.

I am planning on using HttpClient to call the api with the URI i built, but am not sure on how to structure the class. The options i have thought of are:

1. A base class of my implementation so can call it via `base.InvokeURI(Uri myUri)`.
2. A seperation class so it can be used by multiple implementations

I am also unsure where the deserialization should reside.

Comment: Have you looked at [Microsoft Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, at the moment it looks like you are playing Pattern Bingo.

Answer (score 12):

I think using Interface in this case is more suitable:

```
public interface IURLInvoke 
{
    string InvokeURI(Uri myUri);
}

// some implementation
public class YourURLInvoker: IURLInvoke 
{
    public string InvokeURI(Uri myUri)
    {
         // do something
    }
}

public class YourClass 
{
    public IURLInvoke Invoker {get; set;}

    public void InvokeURI(Uri myUri)
    {
         if(Invoker == null)
              return; 

         string xml = Invoker.InvokeURI(Uri myUri);
         // put your code for deserialization here
    }
}

// here is an usage example:
YourClass a = new YourClass();
// set an Invoker, choose a strategy to invoke url
a.Invoker = new YourURLInvoker();
a.InvokeURI(url);
```

This approach is also called [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

> Pls see dummy code using adapter pattern and dependency injection.
>   Idea is to create a interface and pass it around

```
public class Adapter{
 public void processRequest(){
   RequestProcessor processor = new RequestProcessor();
   processor.processRequest();
 }
}

public class RequestProcessor{
  public void procesRequest(){
    Irequest request = new HTTPRequest();
    HTTPService service = new HTTPService();
    // fetch the uri from builder class
    URI url = URIBUIlder();
    string response = service.sendRequest(request,url);
    // now fetch type from just 
    Type t = Serializer.searialize<T>(response);

  }
}

public Class Serializer{
  public static  T searialize<T>(string xml){
  }
}

public interface IRequest{
 public string sendRequest(uri url);
}

public class HTTPRequest:IRequest{
 public string sendRequest(uri url){
  // instantiate actual http request here and return response
 }
}

//This will act as controller
public class HTTPService{
 public string sendRequest(IRequest request,uri url) {
  return request.sendRequest(url);
 }
}
```